# New PC running very slowly

Tags: performance, windows-11

I recently built a new PC with fairly high end specs, but it runs incredibly slowly. By slow, I mean 30 second input lag in games, it takes  about 5 seconds to load windows explorer, dragging windows around the desktop is laggy, everything is slow. Even reinstalling windows takes maybe 50x longer than I'd expect. On a few occasions I've restarted and everything has been super fast, but now not even a restart helps.

Here's a link to benchmark results when it's running slow: https://www.userbenchmark.com/UserRun/60019763 and here's a link to a time when it was working fine after a restart: https://www.userbenchmark.com/UserRun/60019943.

Those links also give an idea of components installed.

The weird thing is that when it's running slow, task manager shows minimal resource usage so it's like it's not even trying.

I have installed the latest version of any driver I can get my hands on, updated the bios, reinstalled windows and now I'm not sure where to go next.

Comment: I'd try installing windows 10 if that's an option, see if you keep having the same problems

Comment: Even the good bench has this comment about your RAM : "ensure that a dual+ channel XMP BIOS profile is enabled", which may indicate a problem with your RAM setup. Although your components are recent, Windows 11 and its new priority scheduling may not be the best fit for you.

Comment: I started installing windows 10 and it's still very slow to install  There's no option for XMP in the bios because I'm on AMD rather than Intel. Did I get the wrong ram? I didn't think it would make much difference.

Comment: What power supply are you using and have you checked all the connections?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sluggishness is often related to a component overheating. You should check the CPU and chipset temps with HWInfo or similar program.

Maybe you checked already so I will suggest the next, not so obvious thing, bad I/O connection. This could be bad SATA cables connection, bad M.2 connection and sometimes even a corrupted flash drive plugged in a USB. You should be careful about where you plug SSD/HDD.

This used to be simpler but some modern boards don't allow to plug M.2 and some of the SATA together as they go on the same line. Check the MB manual to see how they are routed and what is allowed.

Your problem is similar to having 2 drives on the same line. When only 1 communicates it works fine but when you request data from second, both drives generate errors in the data controller. This confuses the CPU causing it to wait for proper reads.

According to Asus site the m.2 slot under the TUF GAMING plate is SATA, so don't use this one for the NVME, use the slot that's next to the CPU.

Comment: It may have been a mix of this and re-seating the ram, but now everything is running at super speed even on Windows 11. It's crazy that it disables the sata ports. Thanks for the assistance!

Comment: @EpicYeti No problem, I am glad that you solved the problem. :)